# Which road connects the most countries?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids

[European Route E80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E80) connects 9 or 10 countries: Portugal, Spain, France, Italy, Croatia, Montenegro, Serbia, (Kosovo), Bulgaria, Turkey, apparently stopping at the Iranian border.

Which officially numbered road connects the largest number of countries?

Comment: To be clear: You are counting the road in Iran despite that it has [a different number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_32_(Iran))?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Finally, no, I'm not.  I was counting it because I thought it was still called E80.  If it's not than it stops in Turkey and is one country less.  Edited question to clarify..

Comment: I do not feel that a road going through several countries by the same name is really one road. More so as many of the European routes have different local numbers and the only reason they are seen internationally as the same road is a number added as an afterthought.

Comment: @Willeke Let's call it a numbered route then.

Comment: In addition to @Willeke points, each segment of the road is paid for and managed for a different, independent entity. And in each of these countries, the "road" is formed by several different roads, of very different type... And, there is any kind of central organization (so if there are repairs in Italy people in Spain get warned beforehand)?

Comment: Numbering can be a tricky business.  The Trans-Canada Highway is one of the longest highways in the world, yet is numbered differently in many Canadian provinces (e.g. highway 1 in BC, Alberta, Saskatchewan, Manitoba, but highways 11 and 17 in Ontario).

Comment: If your criteria is that the number be contiguous, the answer will be Europe or bust. There are highways that run continuously across borders (such as the AlCan Alaska Highway), that are clearly coherent contiguous routes, but the only supernational authority that does anybsort of work applying numbers on roads across muliple clubtries is going to be the EU.

Comment: @LessPop does the EU manage roads?! I doubt it.

Comment: @RHA no, but it does "work applying numbers on roads across [multiple] [countries]", which is all that LessPop is claiming.

Comment: European route numbers are designated by [UNECE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Economic_Commission_for_Europe), not the EU.  They manage some other cross-border issues in addition to road numbering.

Comment: [AH1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AH1) would be the only competitor.

Answer (score 7):

The biggest issue is what defines a road, a country and where a road starts or ends.

That being said, there are two likely candidates:

**Option 1: [The Pan American Highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-American_Highway#Countries_served):**

The Northern Pan-American Highway travels through 9 countries:

```
Canada (unofficial)
United States (interstate system official)
Mexico
Guatemala
El Salvador
Honduras
Nicaragua
Costa Rica
Panama
```

The Southern Pan-American Highway travels through 8 countries:

```
Suriname
Guyana
Venezuela
Colombia
Ecuador
Peru
Chile
Argentina
```

Important spurs also lead into 4 countries:

```
Bolivia
Brazil
Paraguay
Uruguay
```

**Option 2: [AH1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AH1) (with the [E80 extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E80)):**

This travels from Japan through Hong Kong, China, all the way to Turkey, and connects to the E80 to Portugal, connecting over 20 countries.  However, connecting over the ocean is interesting, as is joining two roads, and whether or not you count countries like Hong Kong as actual countries.

However, I'm pretty confident with whatever mechanism you use to measure, the outcome will be one of the above two options.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your example [European Route 40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E40) goes through 10 countries.

France, Belgium, Germany, Poland, Ukraine, Russia, Kazakhstan, Uzbekistan, Turkmenistan, and Kyrgyzstan.